# Is it possible to GROUP_CONCAT two other GROUP_CONCATS?

Tags: mysql

Lets say you have

```
Select 
group_concat(distinct tag.title) as tagTitles
group_concat(distinct tag.id) as tagIds
article.title
FROM table1 JOIN .... WHERE ...
```

Now this returns a row as follow:

```
tagTitles | tagIds  | title
------------------------------------
tag1,ta...|1,2,3,4  | Sample article
```

I would like to concat tagTitles and tagIds into one column so that the output is

```
tags             | title
---------------------------------
tag1=1,tag2=2,...| Sample article
```

How could I achieve this? 
Currently I do this in a for loop after the result are fetched.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to `group_concat()` a `concat()`:

```
Select group_concat(concat(tag.title, '=', tag.id)) as tagTitles
       article.title
FROM table1 JOIN ....
WHERE ...
```